# Rails - NoMethodError in index view, trying to understand ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I will post all of relevent files below, first let me explain the problem. I have 3 models, Players, Teams and Ownerships. Players and Team both own Ownership. Players have a :team through their relationship with Ownerships (has_one :team, through: :ownership).

If I display a Player using the show action, I can access all of the attributes of Team, including the logo that is a paperclip attachment.

If I display all of the Players using the index action, I cannot access any of the Team attributes. If I display the team like this, <%= player.team %> , it displays an object reference like this #Team:0x007fef0b68cb10. If I try and access attributes for Team, <%= player.team.name %>, I get:

```
NoMethodError in Players#index undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

My question is this: How can I create an index method for Players so that I can display the attributes for Team in the index view?

I have tried changing my index method to the following:

```
def index
@players = Player.all.sort_by{ |x| [x.position, x.last_name] }
@Team = Player.team  
end
```

but it fails with

```
 undefined method `team' for #
```

The models:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :team, through: :ownership
has_one :ownership

validates :name, presence: true
validates :position, presence: true

def last_name
self.name.split(' ')[1]
end
end

class Ownership < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :player
belongs_to :team

validates :round, :pick, :team_id, presence: true
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :ownerships
has_many :players, through: :ownerships 

validates :name, presence: true
validates :division, presence: true

 has_attached_file :logo , :styles => { :small => '10>', :medium => '40>', :large => '60>' }
 validates_attachment_content_type :logo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
 end
```

The Players Controller:

```
 class PlayersController < ApplicationController
 def index
 @players = Player.all.sort_by{ |x| [x.position, x.last_name] }
 end

 def not_picked
 @players = Player.all.select { |m| m.team == nil}.sort_by{ |x| [x.position, x.last_name] }
 end

 def show
  @player = Player.find(params[:id])
 end

 private

 def player_params
 params.require(:player).permit(:name, :position)
 end
 end
```

The relevant part of the Players index.html.erb:

```
  <% @players.each do |player| %>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
    <td><%= link_to player.name, player %></td>
    <td><%= player.position %></td>
    <td><%= player.team.name %> </td> <!--This throws the error -->
```

The Players show.html.erb (works fine):

```
 <%= render 'welcome/menu' %>

 <%= @player.name %>

 <%= @player.team.name %>

 <%= @player.ownership.pick %>

 <%= @player.ownership.round %>
```

Comment: You've set this up right, it's just that one of your players doesn't have a `Team` association.  in rails console do `ids = Player.all.pluck(:id)` then `Ownership.where.not(player_id: ids)` - this should show you who doesn't have the association set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like, some of your players don't have an associated team, so `player.team` is `nil` for them. And, in that case it's failing to get the team name with the error message:

```
NoMethodError in Players#index undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Try to use [try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) by changing:

```
<td><%= player.team.name %>
```

To:

```
<td><%= player.try(:team).try(:name) %>
```

And, `Player.team` is wrong, you can't do that as you did not define any  class method `team` in Player class.